# How to handle error when connected to mongodb by mongoosejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

If call the mongoose.connect(...) before mongodb ready, will get an error `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED`, it is ok, but after the mongodb ready, the mongoose won't reconnect, why?

To handle this case, I call `mongoose.disconnect` and at the call back function call mongoose.connect(...) again, like:

```
    connection = mongoose.connect(...).connection;
    connection.on("error", function(err) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            mongoose.disconnect(function(){
            connection = mongoose.connect(...).connection;
        }, 5000);
    });
```

this code can reconnect, but when I start mongodb, the mongodb received too many connections, so I check the `mongoose.disconnect`, it call `connection.close`, and the code is

```
    Connection.prototype.close = function (callback) {
        var self = this;
        this._closeCalled = true;
        switch (this.readyState){
            case 0: // disconnected
                callback && callback();
                break;
            case 1: // connected
            case 4: // unauthorized
                this.readyState = STATES.disconnecting;
                this.doClose(function(err){
```

In my case, connection not ready, so the `readyState` is 0, so  it do nothing, just call the callback function, is it reasonable?

And what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Hey looking like you need to set low value in max-connection-idle-time
So that open ideal connections should get closed automatically by mongodb

http://docs.mlab.com/connecting/#max-connection-idle-time